# Pattern matching failed

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I want to replace `Θ[z + m τ]` by `a[m] Θ[z]`. So I consider the pattern `Θ[z_ + m_ τ]:> a[m] Θ[z]`. It works for almost all value of `m`, however, it seems to fail for `m = 1`, namely,

```
Θ[z+τ]/.{Θ[z_ + m_ τ]:> a[m] Θ[z]}
```

only spits out `Θ[z+τ]` again.

I wonder why this happens, and how to make it work for all `m`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let the pattern matcher know that it can use the default pattern for `Times` by putting a `.` at the end of the `m` pattern.

```
Θ[z + τ] /. {Θ[z_ + m_. τ] :> a[m] Θ[z]}
```

evalutes to `a[1] Θ[z]`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!